# Difference between values folders in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and was looking for a good explanation of the different values folders in my project. such as values, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-v11,  and values-v14. For example, if I want to say fit an older version of android which folder should I put a copy of my dimens.xml file? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The default **`values`** folder would contain the resources to be used by default by your application.

**`values-v11`** and **`values-v14`** contain the resources to be used for API versions 11 and 14 respectively.

The application loads resources from the respective folders based on its API level.

- **`values`** is meant for devices below API 11
- **`values-v11`** is meant for devices with API between 11 and 13
- **`values-v14`** is is meant for devices above API 13

**If nothing is provided explicitly in the specific folders**, then the **default**  **`values`** folder is used.

Similarly, **`values-swXXXdp`** contain the specific resources based on the density and size of the device, if you are looking to implement different resources according to different device sizes. Again, if nothing is provided, the default **`values`** folder is used.

Here is the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)** which would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

The key after the base resource folder name is used to provide alternative resources. There is a great explanation on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) about the types of alternative resources that are supported.

Anything with a v# is for a specific android API level. swXXXdp are for specific device sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the values folder is the default folder, and the contents of the other folders override the default it the condition is met.

For example, you can have a layout with 1 column in "res/layout". And then you make another layout with 2 columns in "res/layout-landscape". Then you start your activity and you see 1 column. When the condition is met (i.e. you put the phone in horizontal position) the layout changes to 2 columns.

You can specify resolutions, pixel densitys, API versions...